# Use RESX file in WPF application with Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, resx

I'm working on a project with WPF/Prism. The application has different modules and one of those modules can change the culture of the resx object. This works fine and each module loaded will display the translated text.

In case any module has already been loaded, the text will not be updated. First, I tried an approach with `x:Static` but quickly realized that a static value doesn't help my issue. Now I've implemented a get-only property in my view model that returns the localized string.

```
public string UserDetailsLabel => Messages.UserDetailsLabel;

<TextBlock Text="{Binding UserDetailsLabel, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
```

However, I have no idea where to tell WPF (or Prism) that the culture has changed and to update the displayed value. The module that changes the culture sets the `Culture` property on `Messages` (generated in `Messages.Designer.cs`).

Is there a way to notify that the value changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to notify that the value changed?

Implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the data-bound `UserDetailsLabel` property.

This is the way to notify WPF that the source value has changed.

In the context of a multi-module Prism application, you could for example use the event aggregator to raise an event that each view model handles by raising the `PropertyChanged` event for all data-bound properties that need to be refreshed in the view.

Comment: I know this is how it's supposed to be done, but the property is get-only, I don't ever set `UserDetailsLabel`. I can't raise the event when changing the culture, because the other module doesn't "know" this one.

Comment: That's where the event aggregator comes in: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/

Comment: Thank you, that's a lot more helpful. I switched from the Loaded event to the event aggregator. This is also really useful for other events that occur in a specific module.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by attaching the `Loaded` event in the `UserControl` xaml definition. The view then asks my view model to update the UI.
The view model then calls `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(UserDetailsLabel))` and updates the view.

```
// UserListView.xaml
<UserControl ... Loaded="UserListView_OnLoaded">...</UserControl>


// UserListView.xaml.cs
private void UserListView_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  var dataContext = (IUserListViewModel) DataContext;
  dataContext.RefreshUI();
}


// UserListViewModel.cs
public void RefreshUI() {
  RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IUserListViewModel));
}
```

Comment: Why would the view tell the view model to update. It should be other way around. Also, this approach won't work if you change the culture once the view has been loaded.

Comment: @mm8 so far, this works and this module is not able to change the culture. I know it isn't perfect, but there is only one module that can change the culture and it updates its own view